# If $\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dy} = 1$, does $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} \frac{d^2 x}{dy^2} = 1$?

Tags: calculus

I know $\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dy} = 1$ because the chain rule says $1 = \frac{dy}{dy} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dy}$.  But does $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} \frac{d^2 x}{dy^2} = 1$?  Or would that be too good to be true?

Comment: Even in the heaven that's not the case. Look at the example $y=x$.

Comment: The simple answer is no because there are plenty of counter examples. Perhaps you could rephrase your question as ....are there any such functions for which this is true?

Comment: It is very likely that you can make a statement about second derivatives by unwinding the inverse function theorem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is true is that (assuming always that $y$ is a one-to-one function of $x$ on some interval)
$$ \eqalign{\dfrac{d^2 x}{dy^2} &= \dfrac{d}{dy} \dfrac{dx}{dy} = \dfrac{dx}{dy} \dfrac{d}{dx} \left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^{-1}\cr
&= - \left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^{-3} \dfrac{d^2 y}{dx^2} }$$

In order to have $\dfrac{d^2 x}{dy^2} \dfrac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = 1$, you'd need
$$ \left(\dfrac {d^2 y}{dx^2}\right)^2 = - \left( \dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^3$$

The solutions of this differential equation include 
$$ y = \dfrac{4}{a+x} + b$$
for constants $a,b$.

Answer (score 6):

If you want an example where the derivatives don't vanish, consider $y=x^3$ (so $x=y^{1/3}$).  Then:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=3x^2
$$ 
and
$$
\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{3}y^{-2/3}=\frac{1}{3}x^{-2}
$$
and
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dy}=3x^2\cdot\frac{1}{3x^2}=1.
$$

On the other hand,
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=6x
$$
and
$$
\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}=-\frac{2}{9}y^{-5/3}=-\frac{2}{9x^5}.
$$
However, 
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}=6x\cdot\left(-\frac{2}{9x^5}\right)=-\frac{4}{3x^4}\not=1.
$$

Answer (score 5):

Consider $y=x$. Then $\frac{dy}{dx} = 1$ and $\frac{dx}{dy} = 1$. However, $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 0 = \frac{d^2x}{dy^2}$.

Answer (score 3):

No it doesn't. Keep in mind that derivatives are *operators*, not variables. Still, that's a good thought process. For a counter-example, see above with $y=x$.